# how to convert a date into an integer in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5.3, strtotime, date-conversion

what I have learnt from the documentation is,I need to make an mutator function which should be getting that value and than converting it into a table.But I am constantly getting the error of **SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'valid_to' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `promotions` (`name`, `city_id`, `valid_to`, `is_active`, `type`, `limit`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (a, Jadah, 2018-02-28, 1, 1, a, 1519818982, 1519818982))**

Model part of the code:

```
public function setValidFromValueAttribute($date)
    {
        $this->attributes['valid_from'] = strtotime($date);
    }
    public function setValidToValueAttribute($date)
    {
        $this->attributes['valid_to'] = intval($date);
    }
```

Blade part of the code for date is

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('valid_from','Valid From') !!}
                    {!! Form::date('valid_from',\Carbon\Carbon::now()) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('valid_to','Valid Till') !!}
                    {!! Form::date('valid_to',\Carbon\Carbon::now()) !!}
                </div>
```

migration part of the code

```
$table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->integer('valid_from')->default(1);
            $table->integer('valid_to')->default(1);
            $table->tinyInteger('is_active');
            $table->tinyInteger('type');
            $table->string('city_id')->default('Jadah');
            $table->string('limit')->unsigined();
            $table->integer('updated_at')->unsigined();
            $table->integer('created_at')->unsigined();
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: $this->attributes['valid_to'] = $date; and in your db set valid_to field as int

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: try `$this->attributes['valid_to'] = strtotime($date);` could you please add your table structure??

Comment: problem is valid_to can't store whatever you are getting from the input. what is the type of  valid_to  you set in DB

Comment: its integer type

Comment: set int value morethan 20 like this int(21)

Comment: ALTER TABLE [table name] MODIFY COLUMN [valid_to] int(21)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i needed to do was to make

```
protected $dates = [
        'valid_from',
        'valid_to'
    ];
```

and remain the valid_from and valid_to into the migration as

```
$table->integer('valid_from');
$table->integer('valid_to');
```

and it all worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Go to `config/database.php`, search for `connections.mysql` array and set:

```
'strict' => false,
```

And your function:

```
public function setValidToValueAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['valid_to'] = strtotime($date);
}
```

Comment: it worked but now my "valid_form" is not getting set

Comment: just check your data type and what data you are providing as date and your code is missing `valid from` when storing i guess

Comment: the value will be like 2018-02-28 which should be string

Comment: `promotions (name, city_id, valid_to, is_active, type, limit, updated_at, created_at) ` here there is no `valid from` attribute, please re-check your save function

Comment: make sure you have `valid_from` in your fillable array

Comment: valid_from is in the fillable array and it is also there in the form but some how it's value is not getting set

Comment: that's weird, try to debug your code step by step and add your controller code and `dd($request->all())` data to get help by others

Answer (score 1):

In your promotion model, add:

```
protected $dates = [
    'valid_from',
    'valid_to'
];
```

Remove the lines

```
public function setValidFromValueAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['valid_from'] = strtotime($date);
}

public function setValidToValueAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['valid_to'] = intval($date);
}
```

In your migration file, replace the lines corresponding to the `valid_from` and `valid_to` as follow

```
 $table->date('valid_from')
 $table->date('valid_to')
```

Comment: by doing 
$table->date('valid_from')
 the values will be automatically be converted into integer???

Comment: It will be an instance of `Carbon`

Answer (score 0):

> If you give limit less than your output you get this error

**EX: 82638628721 this is integer value you get**

> In your DB you give the type as int(5).
>
> 82638628721 > int(5) -> so this error occurs just increase the limit on valid_to field